# How does a Git integrated application know that I can push to the master branch?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

My predicament:

I use Visual Studio and Brackets. Both can have Git integrated into it, however, lets say Visual Studio talks to a repository on GitLab, and Brackets talks to a repository on Github.

How does each application know that I can push to the master branch for each repository, even though the accounts for each website were made with different passwords?

I'm not sure how else to word this, but another tangent:

In Visual Studio, I can override the global username and email. Is this for when I set up the repository with a different email? If someone had my email, couldn't they just push to the master branch in my repository?

How does Git know? I just need a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credentials you use to authenticate your user when logging into the GUI Gitlab or GitHub are not necessarily the same credentials that the Git client program on your computer uses to authenticate when pushing/pulling from the respective remote repositories.

I'm going to assume that SSH is being used here. Not overtly by you, but by the tools you are using. If you aren't entering a password each time you perform a Git operation that communicates with a remote repository and you haven't entered your password into an IDE, then it is certainly the case that you *are* using SSH.

If you are pushing/pulling over SSH protocol, which is very common, then the key-pair on your machine is being used by your computer's Git client, which is used by the IDEs, for authenticating with both Gitlab and GitHub. A cryptographic key-pair has nothing to do with your email or passwords at all. Because some other user doesn't have access to your private key, and probably not even your public key, they would be unable to authenticate over SSH.

Let me know if I can clarify anything for you!

Comment: Okay awesome, makes a lot more sense, but I'm not using SSH and I don't believe my software is either. I simply booted up the program and started using Git, and I was able to push to the master and sync. Is this because the software got the global git user on my machine and found it to match the one hosting the repository?

I did enter my password through the Git Client, so I think that "sets up" my machine as that user. In that regards, how does it also just work for GitLab if I set it up for GitHub?

Comment: Caching of your credentials on your machine varies depending on some configuration as well as the OS you are using. See: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage I mention it because I suppose it may be the case that you are talking to the servers over https instead of SSH. To double check whether or not you are using SSH, log into your Github and Gitlab GUI and go to your account settings and view your keys. Compare the key that lives on your local machine to any that live there. If nothing there or no matches, then your credentials must be cached, else you're using SSH!

Comment: If you are on Mac OSX or Linux, you can find you public key, which is what would be stored as an authorized key on the remote Git server, in the following location `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. The file name `id_rsa.pub` is the most common/default name for an rsa public key.

Comment: @asblargh have I sufficiently answered your question? If so, please click the check mark to the left of my question to mark it as an accepted answer. If not, what more can I help to clarify?